# my app is crash in xcode, but there is no stacktrace for this exception

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, crash, exc-bad-access

[image]
this is a simple game running on iphone device, it will crash in some cases.but xcode only display this message:

```
error: memory read failed for 0xd00000000
```

there is no stack in the left panel. 
i found the value in register pc 0xd00000000, it looks like the base address of this process.
[image]

[image]
i have add a exception breakpoint in xcode it will not active before crash.

this is the memory usage image, i have test it on iphone x:
[image]

so i want to know, how to find the directy reason of this crash? is there any method to break the process when the register change to a special value, in this case, when the pc register change to 0xd00000000, make xcode break.

Comment: out of memory exception

Comment: there are about 400m free memory.

Comment: Are you using ObjC or Swift? Looks like an problem when your read memory from the code segment (since pc and lr registers point to the same address as the memory is read from). Try to enable zombie objects.

Comment: thank you every friends, this is a stackoverflow exception. i have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

stackoverflow exception cause this crash, it make my stack memory crashed,so xcode can't get the valid stacktrace of this tread.